# How to parse strings of json object seperated by comma but not enclosed by array

Tags: go, elasticsearch

In the below sample elasticsearch doument created by the alerting rule, contains 3 comma seperated string of json objects under hits but they are NOT contained in an array [], so in Go unable to parse them.

Can someone help me parse the hits documents

```
[map[_id:2s3kfXoB2vuM1J-EwpE7 _index:alert-X _score:%!s(float64=1) 
     _source:
        map[@timestamp:2021-07-06T22:16:21.818Z 
            alert_name:alert events login 
            hits:
                {"_index":".ds-logs-events-2021.06.30-000005","_type":"_doc","_id":"S83kfXoB2vuM1J-Eo4_v", ... 
                {"_index":".ds-logs-events-2021.06.30-000005","_type":"_doc","_id":"Ss3kfXoB2vuM1J-Eo4_v",...
                {"_index":".ds-logs-events-2021.06.30-000005","_type":"_doc","_id":"N83kfXoB2vuM1J-EiI2l",...
            rule_id:cfb85000-db0e-11eb-83e0-bb11d01642c7 
            ]
```

Model

```
type Alert struct {
    Alert  string   `json:"alert_name"`
    Hits   []*Event `json:"hits"`
}

type Event struct {
    Model  string
    Action string
}
```

Following [offical example](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blame/master/_examples/encoding/easyjson.go)
Using official go-elasticsearch and [easyjson](https://github.com/mailru/easyjson)

Comment: Prepend and append the square brackets, then you can proceed to parse it as a JSON array.

Comment: Thank you @icza 

This question might seem silly, but i was expecting the solution to be complex as was trying get it to work with easyjson for quite some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenated the json string with the array block and was able to Unmarshal it

```
        hitsArray := "[" + alert.Source.Hits + "]"
        var hits []model.AlertHits
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(hitsArray), &hits)
        for _, hit := range hits {
            log.Printf("hit %s action %s", hit.ID, hit.Source.Message.Action)
        }
```

model.go

```
type AlertHits struct {
    ID     string `json:"_id"`
    Source Event  `json:"_source"`
}

type Event struct {
    Message Message `json:"message"`
}

type Message struct {
    Action string `json:"action"`
    Model  string `json:"model"`
}
```